# Accociate a user name to the post they created

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I created a blog post, how can I have my name associated with it? For example, on a page that lists all blog posts, I will see the user name of the post they created. Yes?

In my post controller:

```
public function __construct(Post $post, User $user)
 {
    $this->middleware('auth',['except'=>['index','show',]]);
    $this->post = $post;
    $this->user = $user;
 }

public function show($id)
 {
    $user = $this->user->first(); // This seems to show the first user
    $post = $this->post->where('id', $id)->first(); // Grabs the assigned post
 }
```

In my `show.blade.php`:

```
{{ $user->name }}
```

How can I display the name of the user who created the post? I thought this `$user = $this->user->first();` would work. Im new to Laravel and I am using Laravel 5.

Thanks!

***EDIT***
User Model:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract, BillableContract {

use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

use Billable;


/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';


/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'company_url', 'tagline','company_name', 'company_description'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

/**
 * @var array
 *
 */

protected $dates = ['trial_ends_at', 'subscription_ends_at'];


  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->latest()->where('content_removed', 0);


  }


}
```

Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model {

/**
 * Fillable fields for a new Job.
 * @var array
 */

protected $fillable = [
    'post_title',
    'post_description',
    'post_role',
    'post_types',
    'post_city',
    'post_country',
    'template',
    'content_removed',

];

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}


 public function creator()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }



}
```

Comment: @Epodax Thanks for the correction. A little missed-clicked to add LV4. I am using LV5.

Comment: What does your post model look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first
you need to add the following line to your post model

```
public function creator()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id', 'ID');
}
```

then in you show method

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = $this->post->with('creator')->findOrFail($id);
    return view('show',compact('post'));
}
```

In you show.blade.php

```
{{ $post->creator->name }}
```

Comment: Im now getting : `Cannot access property on non-object` for the show.blade.php I showed you teh User Model so I have now added the Post Model.

Comment: i have tested the code i posted running in my environment , i am curious in the content in you $post variable in show method, mind to post the dd($post) result ?

Comment: I got null. Very strange!

Comment: then im thinking that your post $id is not exists in your database, try the following
`$post = $this->post->with('creator')->findOrFail($id);`

if the record is not found, you will receive a ModelNotFoundException

Comment: You are correct! I thought I've added a post_id but I have deleted the migration to know what is there. Any way to peek at the db table for post? Post id or user id? Id assume user_id.

Comment: you can visit record in your db, with laravel command
`php artisan tinker`
then do
`\App\Post::all()` all existing post will print out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73671/discussion-between-terry-low-and-sylar).